# Firebase Cloud Function Realtime Database Trigger

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

are the realtime database trigger onWrite onCreate queued or threaded ?

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

Cloud Functions events don't necessarily get handled in the same order that they occurred.  If you are depending on ordering, your functions may not work the way you expect.  There is no single ordered queue that all events pass through - this would not scale.

Each function invocation runs full isolation from other function invocations.  Cloud Functions will spin up new server instances to handle load as needed.  So, if one server is busy handling events, Cloud Functions may decide to add more servers to the mix to be able to handle more incoming events.  Each server handles only one event at a time.  The events are handled serially within each server instance, and handled in parallel between server instances.  There is no "threading" going on, from the perspective of the event trigger code (that's not the way node.js works for application code).